# Require Module with Credentials Inside Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I'm using the Twilio library in nodejs. Whenever you require the library, you need to pass the accountSiD and your authToken to load the library.

```
const client = require('twilio')(accountSID, authToken);
```

As of now, I'm working on a project that requires the accountSID and the authToken to be dynamically changed, since the usage can be from different accounts.

To call it, I'm passing the credentials to a function and then inside this, I'm requiring the twilio module.

```
async function sendMessage(accountSID, authToken, params){
    const client = require('twilio')(accountSID, authToken);

    client.messages.create(params).....
}
```

I wanted advice to see if this is really bad practice or it is not that bad since the information is changing.

Since I need to pass an accountSID and a authToken, when I call the module from the beginning, it creates an error that accountSID and authToken are not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is *good* or *bad* practice, but there is a way to do it while still using `require` in the top level scope.

Just do something like this:

```
//Still requiring twilio at the top.
const twilio = require('twilio');

async function sendMessage(accountSID, authToken, params){
    //Twilio is a function, right? Just call twilio in the sendMessage function.
    const client = twilio(accountSID, authToken);

    client.messages.create(params).....
}
```

Good luck and hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! I think this looks cleaner and seems to be working perfectly :)